# how to pass the url into the view context in django?

Tags: django, django-templates

page_title.html

```
<!-- page title -->
        ...
        <ul class="list-inline custom-breadcrumb mb-2">
          <li class="list-inline-item"><a class="h2 text-primary font-secondary" href="{% url 'teacher-list' %}">{{list_title}}</a></li>
        ...
<!-- /page title -->
```

views.py

```
class TeacherDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Teacher
    context_object_name = "teacher"
    template_name = "users/teacher_detail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['list_title'] = "Our Teachers"
        return context
```

So currently have a teacher_detail page, on that page there is a page_title section (which is being included inside other templates) which has a url that allows you to go to the list view version of it, in this case it is the teacher_list page. The problem is that i have multiple pages with similar design, i know how that i can pass in the list_view variable as a part of the view context which makes it dynamically displayed depending on the page. I wonder how i can also pass in the url as a dynamic variable into the view context like:

```
context['list_url'] = "{% url 'teacher-list %}"
```

so that i don't have to repeat it and also will be able to reuse the page_title sub template?

Answer (score 1):

two options:

1. in view:

```
context['list_url'] = reverse('teacher-list')
```

in html:

```
... href="{{list_url}}"
```

or

2. in view:

```
context['list_url'] = 'teacher-list'
```

in html:

```
... href="{% url list_url %}"
```